# SPonline : error when create an alert

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, alert

My users had a "Designer" grade and get this error when I create an alert :[image: error]

Since I have tried on a test account with the same grades (Its worked).
I dont know how to investigate on this problem.

Comment: I have found the difference: my test account had the "Sharepoint Admin" Status

Comment: What is "SharePoint admin" status? Which permission does "SharePoint Admin" status? To create alerts, the account needs to have "Create Alert" base permission level. So, check the "Designer" permission level and make sure it also contains "Create Alerts" base permission level.

Answer (score 0):

To 'Manage Alerts' for other users, you need Full Control - as you mention in your comments.  The test account is the Sharepoint Admin account, so it sounds like this account has 'Full Control'.  For further info use [this link to a MS page on permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

Comment: When i go in the "check autorisations", it gives me the same for my 2 account.
I have already added the "Manage Alerts" for 'Designer' group..

Comment: BTW - it's not good practise to customise the default groups.  So, to take your example, it would be better to create a new group e.g. 'Designer2' and give that new group the 'Manage Alerts' permission.  Otherwise it is very difficult for other sharepoint administrators to manage sharepoint - since sharepoint will behave in unexpected ways and will cause confusion.

Comment: Yes, I know but im the only administrator and the site content only one component.